# Django/authentification: how to make login page = home page?

Tags: django, authentication

I develop Django web app using Django authentification backend.
It works without having to define any views or forms, only template to 'bootstrap' it.

But I would like to change 'navigation' url and probably 'redesign' template using django-crispy-form.

But the first step is make user directly access Login page when the 'root' url (https://<my_domain>/) is enter in the navigation adress bar.

Currently, user access home page of my web app that contain a login button that redirect to https://<my_domain>/registration/login

Do I need to override all authentification views (and forms for design) and change url as needed?

Or is there an easiest way, maybe using settings.py to make user redirect to login page from root url?

**project**

```
- app
   - core
       - settings
           - base.py
           - ...
       - views.py
       - urls.py
   - app1
       - forms.py
       - views.py
       - templates
           - app1
   - registration                             # <= currently no forms.py nor views.py
       - templates
           - registration
              - login.html
              - password_change_done.html
              - ...
   - static
   - templates
       - layout
           - base.html
       - home.html
```

**core/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),                            # <= 'root' url
    # path('registration/', include('registration.urls')),        # <= registration views override
    path('registration/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

**core/settings.py**

```
LOGIN_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: I got an error: page is not correctly redirected

Comment: just use ``@login_required`` decoretor on your home page user will automatically redirected to login page when they visits your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have that:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'home'
```

Use classic solution:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

And then use decorator mentioned by @AnkitTiwari if you operate in `Function Based Views` just on top on `home` view:

```
@login_required
def home_view(request):
```

Or `LoginRequiredMixin` in `Class Based Views`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
```